# Python - Get redirected url of links from Google Alerts feeds

Tags: python, rss, google-alerts

If you create a google alert as a rss feed (not automaticcaly sent to your e-mail address), it contains links like this one: https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://www.statesmanjournal.com/story/opinion/readers/2014/10/13/gmo-labels-encourage-people-make-choices/17171289/&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGjkyZjE1NGUzMGIwZjRkNGQ6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNHrCLmbml7baTXaqySagcuKHp-KHA.

This link is obviously a redirection (just try it and you'll end up here: http://www.statesmanjournal.com/story/opinion/readers/2014/10/13/gmo-labels-encourage-people-make-choices/17171289/), but I cannot get this final url with Python (otherwise than by removing the beginning of the url, which is quite ugly).

I've tried so far with packages urllib2, httplib2 and requests:

- urllib2.urlopen and geturl() from the return value
- httplib2 request with follow_all_redirects=True and 'content-location' from the return value
- requests.get and history from the return value

Has someone already been confronted to this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us at least *some* of your code and what that outputs, as well as what you *expected* to be output instead? I'm not sure I am following what you are asking here.

Comment: The response from Google does **not** produce a 30x redirect. It gives you JavaScript code instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does **not** give you a HTTP redirect; a 200 OK response is returned, not a 30x redirect:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://www.statesmanjournal.com/story/opinion/readers/2014/10/13/gmo-labels-encourage-people-make-choices/17171289/&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGjkyZjE1NGUzMGIwZjRkNGQ6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNHrCLmbml7baTXaqySagcuKHp-KHA'
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> response.url
u'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://www.statesmanjournal.com/story/opinion/readers/2014/10/13/gmo-labels-encourage-people-make-choices/17171289/&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGjkyZjE1NGUzMGIwZjRkNGQ6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNHrCLmbml7baTXaqySagcuKHp-KHA'
>>> response.text
u'<script>window.googleJavaScriptRedirect=1</script><script>var m={navigateTo:function(b,a,d){if(b!=a&&b.google){if(b.google.r){b.google.r=0;b.location.href=d;a.location.replace("about:blank");}}else{a.location.replace(d);}}};m.navigateTo(window.parent,window,"http://www.statesmanjournal.com/story/opinion/readers/2014/10/13/gmo-labels-encourage-people-make-choices/17171289/");\n</script><noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://www.statesmanjournal.com/story/opinion/readers/2014/10/13/gmo-labels-encourage-people-make-choices/17171289/\'"></noscript>'
```

The response is a piece of HTML and JavaScript that your browser will interpret as loading a new URL. You'll have to *parse* that response to extract the target.

String splitting could achieve that:

```
>>> response.text.partition("URL='")[-1].rpartition("'\"")[0]
u'http://www.statesmanjournal.com/story/opinion/readers/2014/10/13/gmo-labels-encourage-people-make-choices/17171289/'
```

If we assume that the `URL` parameter in the body is just a direct reflection of the `url` parameter in the query string, then you can just extract it from there too, and we don't even have to ask Google to execute the redirect:

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlsplit
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from urlparse import parse_qs, urlsplit

target = parse_qs(urlsplit(url).query)['url'][0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll use this!

Comment: if you end up with extracting the URL from response then better to extract it from the original URL

Comment: @brainLoop: if we presume that the `url` component is the same, then sure, and then don't even bother to ask Google.